# How to bin a 2D data along the x-axis with Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, binning

[image]

I have two arrays of corresponding data (x and y) that I plot as above on a log-log plot. The data is currently too granular and I would like to bin them to get a smoother relationship. Could I get some guidance on how I can bin along the x-axis, in **exponential** bin sizes, so that it appears linear on the log-log scale?

For example, if the first bin is of range x = 10^0 to 10^1, I want to collect all y-values with corresponding x in that range and average them into one value for that bin. I don't think np.hist or plt.hist quite does the trick, since they do binning by counting occurrences.

Edit: For context, if it helps, the above plot is an assortativity plot that plots the in vs out degree of a certain network.

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`scipy.stats.binned_statistic`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html) to get the mean of the data in each bin. The bins would best be created via `numpy.logspace`. You may then plot those means e.g. as horiziontal lines spanning the bin width or as scatter at the mean position.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.logspace(0,5,300)
y = np.logspace(0,5,300)+np.random.rand(300)*1.e3


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y, s=9)

s, edges, _ = binned_statistic(x,y, statistic='mean', bins=np.logspace(0,5,6))

ys = np.repeat(s,2)
xs = np.repeat(edges,2)[1:-1]
ax.hlines(s,edges[:-1],edges[1:], color="crimson", )

for e in edges:
    ax.axvline(e, color="grey", linestyle="--")

ax.scatter(edges[:-1]+np.diff(edges)/2, s, c="limegreen", zorder=3)

ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This works almost as I need, except that I prefer to plot data points instead of lines representing the mean of the bins. The y data points are already in array s. To obtain the plottable x data points (mean of each bin), I did `for left_edge,right_edge in zip(edges,edges[1:]): x.append(np.mean([left_edge,right_edge]))`, where `x` is initialized as an empty list. This calculates the center point of each bin by taking the average of the two edges of each bin. Then I `plt.plot(x,s,'s')`. And I get what I need!

Comment: You can use `ax.scatter(edges[:-1]+np.diff(edges)/2)`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with pandas. The idea is to assign each X value to an interval using `np.digitize`. Since you are using a log scale, it makes sense to use `np.logspace` to choose intervals of exponentially changing lengths. Finally, you can group X values in each interval and compute mean Y values.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x_max = 10

xs = np.exp(x_max * np.random.rand(1000))
ys = np.exp(np.random.rand(1000))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': xs,
    'Y': ys,
})

df['Xbins'] = np.digitize(df.X, np.logspace(0, x_max, 30, base=np.exp(1)))
df['Ymean'] = df.groupby('Xbins').Y.transform('mean')
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='X', y='Ymean')
```

Comment: Yakim, your answer will greatly benefit from adding logx=True, logy=True to the df.plot command. The linear scale produces a weird looking plot. It will also be good to show the output of your code.

Comment: Thank you! This works as I need. Could you explain briefly the groupby step, what the code is doing? I'm trying to read the groupby documentation but that is long and pretty confusing.

Comment: `groupby('Xbins')` goes over subsets of rows of `df` with the same value in `Xbins` column. For each such subset, we compute the mean value of `Y` column with `Y.transform('mean')`. The `transform` method` simply means that the output has the same shape as the original `df`. Documentation should cover alternative applications with `apply` and `agg`.